Lifting subextension of residue fields
Let $F \subset L$ be a arbitrary extension of valued fields with associated extension of residue fields $k \subset l$. Suppose we are given a subextension $k\subset k'\subset l$ can we always find an extension  $F \subset F'\subset L$ such that the residue field of $F'$ is $k'$? If you prefer you may assume all valuations are complete and discrete.

"If you prefer you may assume all valuations are complete and discrete." Is this copied from an exercise by a polite instructor? What is the context of your questions, and what have you tried so far?

Definitely not copied from anywhere. Reading that sentence again it does sound a bit odd since most of the time we only think of discrete valuations (I am working withHenselian Krull valuations today so it made sense in my head). I think it should be true but I don't what is the shortest justification is. It is clear to me for transcendental and separable extensions, so it would be enough to do the case where $k\subset k'$ is purely inseparable. However, I was hoping to find a simple one sentence proof or reference. I am trying to keep a certain technical proof short...

It is not always possible to find such an intermediate field: let $K$ be a field of characteristic $0$, $v$ a valuation on $K$ such that the residue field $k_0$ of $v$ has characteristic $p\neq 0$. Consider the rational function field $L:=K(x,y)$ in two indeterminates over $K$. On $L$ we can define the Gauß-extension $w$ of $v$ with respect to $x,y$, which for polynomials is defined as
$
w(\sum\limits_{i,j}a_{i,j}x^iy^j):=\min (v(a_{i,j}) : a_{i,j}\neq 0).
$
The residue field of $w$ is $l=k_0(\overline{x},\overline{y})$, where the residues $\overline{x},\overline{y}$ of $x,y$ are algebraically independent over $k_0$.
Let $F:=K(x^p,y^p)$. Then $L|F$ is a separable extension of degree $p^2$ and the residue field of $w|_F$ is $k=k_0(\overline{x}^p,\overline{y}^p)$. Hence $l|k$ is a purely inseparable extension of degree $p^2$. Since $l|k$ cannot be generated by one element, this extension possesses infinitely many intermediate fields. The extension $L|F$ however possesses only finitely many of them.
